# IE 11 - DataTables DOM performance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datatables

I have a HTML table with 500 rows and the following piece of js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.time('init apples');
        $('#myApples').DataTable();
        console.timeEnd('init apples');
    }); 
</script>
```

I ran a test on these three browsers:

**IE 11:** 
init apples: 4.807,458ms 
init apples: 4.424,716ms 
init apples: 5.007,424ms 
init apples: 4.368,084ms 
init apples: 4.354,414ms

**Chrome:** 
init apples: 128.066ms 
init apples: 154.445ms 
init apples: 139.853ms 
init apples: 157.234ms 
init apples: 130.374ms

**Firefox:** 
init apples: 286.96ms 
init apples: 255.26ms 
init apples: 268.33ms 
init apples: 242.93ms 
init apples: 249.12ms

I wonder, why is it so slow and if there is a way to speed it up?

Comment: i look at the pictures most of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some further research and browsing 9gag i found out, that the render engine of IE is very slow in contrast to chrome and firefox, when it comes to manipulating the DOM.

the only way to speed it up was to change it to an ajax driven datatable.

for spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/applesAsJson", produces = "application/json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JSONArray AppleController.allApplesAsJson() {
    List<Apple> apples = Apple.findAllApples();
    return Apple.toJsonArray(apples);
}
```

json:

```
[{"id":"1", "name":"Granny", "color":"green"},
 {"id":"2", "name":"Lenny", "color":"red"}]
```

datatable:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/applesAsJson',
    cache : false,
    type : 'GET',
    }).done(function(data) {

    console.time('init apples');
    $('#myApples').DataTable({
        "aaData": data,
        "columns": [
             { "data": "id" },
             { "data": "name" },
             { "data": "color" }
         ],
         "bProcessing": true,
         "bDeferRender": true
    });
    console.timeEnd('init apples');
}
```

the render function was very usefull to do all kinds of markup magic:

```
{ "data": null, "className": "details-control",
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return '<img src="/apples/getImage/'+ full.id +'"></img>';
      }
}
```

bDeferRender option made it like 15% faster.

**IE 11:**
ca. 180 ms

**Chrome:**
ca. 60ms

**Firefox:**
ca. 140ms